# ASNE library get access token

Tags: android, access-token

Did anybody use [ASNE](https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE) library which work with Social Networks. I can not get access token of social networks. Result of my request is always null. How to get access token.

Here is my code which should get access token:

```
facebookImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int networkId = 0;
            networkId = FacebookSocialNetwork.ID;

            SocialNetwork sn = mSocialNetworkManager.getSocialNetwork(networkId);
            if (!sn.isConnected()){
                if(networkId != 0) {
                    sn.requestLogin();

                    sn.requestAccessToken(new OnRequestAccessTokenCompleteListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onRequestAccessTokenComplete(int i, AccessToken accessToken) {
                            Log.d("My_access_token_fb", accessToken.toString());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(int i, String s, String s1, Object o) {

                        }
                    });

                    Log.d("My_access_token", sn.getAccessToken().toString());
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Wrong networkId", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                startProfile(sn.getID());
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be right, try to use:

```
sn.getAccessToken().toString()
```

Instead:

```
sn.requestAccessToken()
```